# Linux kernel Tree-USB Driver compilation

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, usb-drive

I got to delete a module(`usb-storage.ko`) from

`/lib/modules/KERNEL-VERSION/kernel/drivers/usb/storage/` directory named `usb-storage.ko`

Are there any specific source files inside `linux/drivers/usb/storage` diractory which results in `usb-storage.ko`?

Please let me know what are the files I can bring to a local directory for compilation to generate a similar `usb-storage.ko` module.

or even I am curious to know if I can compile this as a module along with the Kernel compilation process *(But only`usb-storage.ko` should be compiled)*

Thanks for response !!

Answer (score 1):

To compile usb-storage.ko as module, you need to enable only CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=y and make all the other option disable. This could be done from kernel configuration menu (i.e make menuconfig):

```
      Device Drivers 
            USB Support
                <M> USB Mass Storage Support
```

"USB Mass Storage Support" requires "Support for Host-Side USB", so it'll be selected too. So, select it from kernel configuration option via above location.

And to compile the only usb-storage.ko without recompiling the whole kernel every time, need to do the following:

```
              "make drivers/usb/storage"
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: yes I did the same, but it could not produce `usb-storage.ko`
Any clue, if it has some dependencies which need to be included !!

Comment: I'm not sure how did you build the kernel. Have you done - "make modules bzImage" then, "make modules_install; make install;" first command to build the kernel, later commands are to install modules under /lib/$(uname -r)/modules ...

Comment: I've just reproduced on my system, what I've said. You'll get the usb-storage.ko module under /lib/module/$(uname -r)/kernel/driver/usb/storage/ directory.

Comment: yes you are correct. But I dont want to compile the other modules unnecessarily.

Comment: do "make drivers/usb/storage", but if other modules aren't compiled then they'll be too.

Comment: yes, that is the solution I just got.
thanks for your response !!

Comment: I've edited my question a bit, to focus that it address your problem perticularly.